# Planning on reworking the paladin handbook

Tags: dnd-3.5e, paladin

I am planning on reworking the [paladin handbook](http://dictummortuum.blogspot.gr/2011/08/paladins-handbook.html). I believe that we know the state of D&D 3.5e as a whole, so I am in a much better position to create a guide that won't need to be updated whenever a new sourcebook is released.

The new information that I am going to introduce to the guide is a more thorough breakdown of the paladin class. I'm planning on having the following arbitrary aspects:

- The **champion** is the warrior aspect; a champion paladin tries to optimize his main combat skill, smite evil, in order to deal high amounts of damage.
- The **cavalier** is the horseman; a cavalier paladin improves his performance in combat by focusing on the synergy between him and the special mount.
- The **templar** is the aspect with the most connection to the divine. A templar paladin uses spells. turn undead, [domain] and [divine] feats to increase his combat prowess.
- The **lord** is the leader of the group. A lord paladin supports his followers by applying buffs and acting as the party face with his skills.

This way a player can focus on the aspect(s) that he prefers and maximize it.

- Do you find this class breakdown useful?
- Would you change any of the names to something more fitting?
- Would you like it if the combinations (e.g. lord-cavalier or templar-champion) had distinct names and description?
- Are there any other aspects that I am missing?
- Would you move an ability to a different aspect? (e.g. skills to the templar)

Thank you in advance,
Dimitris

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is really not equipped to handle this kind of thing. Questions need to be focused and answers need to at least plausibly be authoritative. This much too open-ended, and it has to be; no one could tell you authoritatively which would be the “right” way to do this. If you are interested in the opinions of some of the people on this site, a chatroom in [Chat] might be appropriate, but the Q&A functionality cannot handle this.